# Load an invalid XML in PHP DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have and input XML file that is not correctly formatted ( ie. it has '&' instead of '& amp;')
When i try to load this XML using PHP DOM, $doc->load("file.xml") it throws and error and stops the parsing.

Is there any way to load this un-formatted XML? and No I cant edit the source XML file.
I did try using $doc->loadHTML() but it throws errors all over the place.

I wanted to know if there is a proper way to do this (like load file contents and change it using regex or something similar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check that it's the `&` that's causing the error and not something else.

One way or another, you'll have to modify the XML to get it parsed. The HTML in `loadHTML` is loaded from a string, can't you just replace the invalid characters with the correct ones?

If your installation supports the PHP Tidy extension (http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) you could try to clean it up with that, though in my experience it's far from foolproof.

Comment: Yes, it is the ampersand that is causing the trouble. I just don't want to replace all the & with &-amp; cause then when i get a valid xml as input it will cause problems. i dont know much about the tidy extension. It looks more of an HTML tool and cudnt find an appropriate function for XML cleanup.

Comment: I searched a lil bit more and Tidy seems to solve the problem. This is what i did: `$config = array(
   'indent' => true,
   'input-xml' => true,
   'output-xml' => true ); $clean = $tidy->repairString(file_get_contents($file), $config); `

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `$doc->validateOnParse = false;` before loading your XML via `$doc->loadHTML(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that's the only thing making it not validate, then you could try loading the file into a string with `file_get_contents()` function, then search & replace through the string to change the &'s into `&amp;`'s, then place that string into simpleXML like `$xml = simplexml_load_string($cleaned_string);`

Comment: As posted in reply to the above poster, That would cause problems when i load a valid xml.